# R group_by() + rleid() equivalent in Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, run-length-encoding

I've got a following data frame in Python:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'measurement_id': np.repeat([1, 2], [6, 6]),
                         'min': np.concatenate([np.repeat([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2]), 
                                                np.repeat([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2])]),
                         'obj': list('AB' * 6),
                         'var': [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]})
```

First, within each group defined by `object`, I'd like to assign id to unique run of `measurement_id` and `var` columns. If any value of those columns changes, it starts new run that should be assigned with new id. So the

```
df['rleid_output'] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3]
```

Then, for each group defined by `rleid_output` I'd like to check how many minutes (`min` column) the run lasted giving me `expected_output` column:

```
df['expected_output'] = [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3]
```

If it was R, I'd proceed as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(measurement_id = rep(1:2, each = 6),
           min = rep(rep(1:3, each = 2), 2),
           object = rep(LETTERS[1:2], 6),
           var = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1))
df %>% 
  group_by(object) %>% 
  mutate(rleid = data.table::rleid(measurement_id, var)) %>% 
  group_by(object, rleid) %>% 
  mutate(expected_output = last(min) - first(min) + 1)
```

So the main thing I need is R `data.table::rleid` equivalent that would work with Python `pd.DataFrame.groupby` clause. Any ideas how to solve this?

@Edit: new, updated example of data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'measurement_id': np.repeat([1, 2], [6, 6]),
                         'min': np.concatenate([np.repeat([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2]), 
                                                np.repeat([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2])]),
                         'obj': list('AB' * 6),
                         'var': [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]})
df['rleid_output'] = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3]
df['expected_output'] = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer**

The problem is that the `min` column in each group of `measurement_id, obj, var` should be maintained order. We can check this by group by on `measurement_id, obj, var` and then checking if the difference in `min` column is greater than `1`. If so, we mark it as a unique duration in `expected_output`:

```
df['grouper'] = (df.groupby(['measurement_id', 'obj', 'var'])['min']
                 .apply(lambda x: x.diff().fillna(1).eq(1))
                )

df['expected_output'] = (
    df.groupby(['measurement_id', 'obj', 'var'])['grouper'].transform('sum').astype(int)
)

df = df.drop(columns='grouper')

    measurement_id  min obj  var  expected_output
0                1    1   A    1                1
1                1    1   B    2                2
2                1    2   A    2                1
3                1    2   B    2                2
4                1    3   A    1                1
5                1    3   B    1                1
6                2    1   A    2                2
7                2    1   B    1                3
8                2    2   A    2                2
9                2    2   B    1                3
10               2    3   A    1                1
11               2    3   B    1                3
```

---

**Old answer, following OP's logic**

We can achieve this by using `GroupBy.diff` to get your `rleid_output`, basically a unique identifier each time `var` changes for each `measurement_id`& `obj`

After that using `GroupBy.nunique` to measure the amount of `minutes`:

```
rleid_output = df.groupby(['measurement_id', 'obj'])['var'].diff().abs().bfill()
df['expected_output'] = (df.groupby(['measurement_id', 'obj', rleid_output])['min']
                         .transform('nunique'))

    measurement_id  min obj  var  expected_output
0                1    1   A    1                2
1                1    1   B    2                2
2                1    2   A    1                2
3                1    2   B    2                2
4                1    3   A    2                1
5                1    3   B    1                1
6                2    1   A    2                2
7                2    1   B    1                3
8                2    2   A    2                2
9                2    2   B    1                3
10               2    3   A    1                1
11               2    3   B    1                3
```

Comment: There are two traps in your original solution (marked as old answer now) - an use of `bfill` to fill `NaN` values and `nunique` for counting minutes. The latter would fail if some intermediate values of `min` are lacking and the former would fail for if the value of `var` has changed in second `min`, e.g. `'var': [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]`

Comment: Also, your updated answer would fail if one object, let's say `A`, has value of `var` equal to `1` in 1st minute, then equal to `2` in 2nd minute, and equal to `1` again in 3rd minute.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the new dataframe where my answer will not suffice, so I can adjust accordingly.

Comment: Does your expected output also change with the new example df?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204952/discussion-between-erfan-and-jakes).

Answer (score 2):

To mimic the behaviour of R `rleid` function one can firstly create an artificial column that checks if current value has changed in comparison to previous one or not. In this case, we should do this on grouped `var` Series:

```
var_grpd = df.groupby(['measurement_id', 'obj'])['var']
df['tmp'] = (var_grpd.shift(0) != var_grpd.shift(1))
```

Then, we can use this artificial `tmp` column to obtain `rleid_output2`. After that, `tmp` column is no longer needed.

```
df['rleid_output2'] = df.groupby('obj')['tmp'].cumsum().astype(int)
df.drop('tmp', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Finally, to check how many minutes `var` value lasts, we can calculate the difference between last and first minute within a group.

```
df['expected_output2'] = df.groupby(['obj', 'rleid_output2'])['min'] \
                           .transform(lambda x: x.iat[-1] - x.iat[0] + 1)
```

`.iat` is similar to `.iloc` but allows us to access single value in `DataFrame` or `Series`.